# Apply indent to stdout?

Tags: python

I have a program that I just prefere to have everything indented, I feel like it makes the output a lot more digestible with a space on the left hand side of the text.

I've found the class textwrap() in python which does a great job out writing a paragraph to the output, however I have the following code:

```
cli = cmd.Cmd()
cli.columnize(list, displaywidth=110)
```

Which does a great job of displaying the columns but there is no way to add an indent to it.

I was wondering, is there any fancy way in python to have ALL my **stdout** output indented?  That way I wouldnt need to add a '\t' to the beginning of every line.

If there isn't, how can I output that `columnize()` command with an indent?

Comment: You can design a wrapper stream that does this.

Comment: @Barmar any pointers on how?

Comment: I can't find a tutorial on this, you'll have to study the `io` class and figure it out. It's not something beginners typically do.

Answer (score 1):

The would "override" the `cli` instances stdout, not only `columnize()`:

```py
import cmd
import sys


class Indent:

    def __init__(self, indent_char):
        self.indent_char = indent_char

    @staticmethod
    def flush():
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def write(self, string):
        sys.stdout.write(self.indent_char + string)


cli = cmd.Cmd(stdout=Indent("\t"))
cli.columnize(["12345", "67890"], displaywidth=110)
```

Output:

```
    12345  67890
```